# VBA: Calling a Function

Tags: vba, function, excel

I'm trying to clean up my coding overall.  To do that, I want to turn a lot of my code into functions.

In Java, it worked similarly (exactly?) how I have the code below.

The line `OriginateDateItems()` would execute the following function:

```
Function OriginateDateItems()

currentMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm") 'July
currentDate = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") '06-09-15
currentYear2char = Format(Date, "yy") '15
currentYear4char = Format(Date, "yyyy") '2015
currentFiscalMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Date), "mm") '08
wsDate = currentFiscalMonth & currentYear4char '082015

End Function
```

Would anyone be able to explain how to call a function without using `=` or something of the sort?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are not returning anything, just make it a sub. Also you can just also call the function.

Comment: How would I just call the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Function` always returns a value. So it's meant to be used as `something = OriginateDateItems()`

Now a `Sub` is meant to simply run something.

If you write your function as a sub:

```
Sub OriginateDateItems()

    currentMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm") 'July
    vcurrentDate = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") '06-09-15
    currentYear2char = Format(Date, "yy") '15
    currentYear4char = Format(Date, "yyyy") '2015
    currentFiscalMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Date), "mm") '08
    wsDate = currentFiscalMonth & currentYear4char '082015

End Sub
```

Then all your vars (currentMonth, currentYear, etc) must be global (outside any sub), otherwise they are not visible.

Just call it like

```
Call OriginateDateItems
```

If you want your sub to return them to the code that called it, you can pass all parameters as  `ByRef`:

```
Sub OriginateDateItems(ByRef CurrentMonth, byref vcurrentDate, .....)

    currentMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm") 'July
    vcurrentDate = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") '06-09-15
    currentYear2char = Format(Date, "yy") '15
    currentYear4char = Format(Date, "yyyy") '2015
    currentFiscalMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Date), "mm") '08
    wsDate = currentFiscalMonth & currentYear4char '082015

End Sub
```

Then you call it like:

```
 Call OriginateDateItems(currentMonth, vcurrentDate, currentyeartoChar......)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a sub not a function. A function is used to return a value.

Change

```
Function OriginateDateItems()
```

to

```
Sub OriginateDateItems()
```

Then just call it by

```
OriginateDateItems
```

You don't need the () to call a sub.
To call a function you would

```
value = functionName()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the Function one of two ways:

```
'calling function without parentheses
OriginateDateItems

'calling function with parentheses
Call OriginateDateItems()
```

It is likely the editor will drop your parentheses in the second example if your function has no parameters.

As Chuck mentioned, you can also change "Function" in your code to "Sub" if it returns no value. It is the equivalent of "void Function" in Java. This has no effect whatsoever on the calling syntax above unless you have parameters.

Parentheses are required if you have parameters and use Call or return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your

```
Function OriginateDateItems()
```

To a Sub

```
Sub OriginateDateItems()
```

Then you can call your function by its name